# JavaFX and the icons of buttons of Summernote

Tags: javafx-8, summernote, javafx-webengine

I'm trying to integrate Summernote in my JavaFX application.
In order to prevent user manipulation of HTML files, **I must integrate Summernote inside the JAR file**.
Unfortunately when I do that, the Summernote icons disappear.
I've thinked that problem was in summernote.css, in the "src" property of the @font-face. So I've tried to change that value in any possibile way, but nothing to do: the icons of the buttons are not showed :-( 
All works fine (that is, js and css are correctly loaded and the editor works fine), but I'm not able to show the icons of the buttons.

The code that I use, in one JavaFX controller, to load the HTML of the Summernote inside a webEnigne is this:

```
URL urlEditor = getClass().getResource("/it/alessandrostella/epub/view/summerNote.html");
editorWebEngine.load(urlEditor.toExternalForm());
```

This is the code inside summerNote.html (it works):
[image]

The Summernote binaries are located in this JAR folder:
it/alessandrostella/epub/view/library/summerNote
[image]

And this is what happens in my application:
[image]

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: The declaration of icon path is done into html?Where the icons are located into?Exporting to jar file is different than running the project into an IDE.

Comment: Hi @GoXR3Plus . Thanks for your question.

In these hours I've searched a solution... It seems that Summernote does not "contains" the icons that it uses. It seems that Summernote downloads the icons from a repository. I've found these informations here:

[link](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/505)

So, I've tried to insert the "Font-Awesome" icons inside the same JAR, but nothing is changed... :-(

Comment: Have a look here http://www.devlabs.ninja/article/font-awesome-icons-in-a-javafx-application

Comment: Nothing to do :-(
All that is written on Devlabs works perfectly (I've tried), but it fails when there is summernote (or any other WYSIWYG editor) :-(
It seems that when a visual editor tries to read its css and the CSS is inside a JAR... nothing works :-(
Now I want to try an extreme experiment! I'll try to copy all CSS summernote code, inside the HTML where summernote works... But I'm not optimistic.

Comment: ... **of course it didn't work** :-(
At this point I'm seriously thinking to **leave all summenote files out of JAR** and loading summernote not as "resource" but as file. In this moment I can't see no other solution...

Comment: Check it to see if it works that way.Although don't convert all the code before you are actually sure that it works.I have no personal experience with summernote but it is starting making me curious how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check the the path of the fontawesome sources or icons located on summernote css files , I fixed this problem by modifying the path.